# Can Pay Pal In-App Purchase be Included in a Free App..?

Tags: android, paypal

I am working on an application, which is intended to be free for the users in the Android Market. But, in the application, there is some section, which is a paid section and that payments would be through a Payment Processor, in my case through Pay Pal.

I have gone through [Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement.](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html)

especially section 3.3, to extent I have understood it, it seems that you are violating the agreement if you include in-app purchase in a free app. But I am confused, whether I should include in-app purchase section in the app or should my app be a paid app. Suggestions and Explanations are always welcomed.

Comment: You posted this back in March. What course of action did you decide upon?

Answer (score 3):

In-app purchase is permitted and encouraged in free apps, as long as you use whatever Google gives you. You're not allowed to use third-party payment options in apps published on the Android Market though, and by doing that you are risking exclusion from the Android Market.

Comment: It seems deceptive to mark an app as free but then try to charge someone. In the interests of being a good, ethical businessperson, it's probably a good idea to list any fees in the description.

Comment: @ Zrgiu... App is yet to be published. Now, from your explanation I understand that I can't use third party payment option but I can use it through Google Checkout. Is it so..???

Comment: @jmort253 ... You are absolutely right that, it is not ethical to mark something free, and then charge for it... So you are saying I must mention in the app description that, this app contains an in-app purchase, but app downloading is free..????

Comment: @UsamaSarwar - If I were marketing something and was expecting payment, I wouldn't mark it as free. In my experience, being deceptive doesn't facilitate repeat business. In other words, if you don't want a bunch of 1 star feedback with people saying bad, nasty things about you, you should be sure not to surprise your users with any fees they're not expecting :)

Comment: @everyone There are perfectly legitimate cases where you would need to use in-app purchases. Take for example an app that gives you 500 free sms, but then you can buy tokens to have another 500 sms messages. As long as the Android Market description clearly specifies this behavior so the users know exactly what they're downloading, then I don't see why this would be immoral in any way.

Comment: @UsamaSarwar - Yes, that is so. You must use the in-app purchase for Android sdk released by google for the version of your apps that are published on the Android Market. You are also free to build different version to publish on other stores, that can use the PayPal API or any other payment processor

Comment: @jmort253 All the major ebook reader apps (Kindle, Nook, Google Play) are free apps that charge for in-app content (when you buy a book). Are they all unethical?

Answer (score 3):

It is okay to have In-App Purchase in a "free" app, in Android Market (now Google Play Store).  It is okay to have PayPal IAP, in an app that is *not* distributed through the Google Play Store.  It is *not* okay to have PayPal IAP (or any other non-Google IAP) in any app, paid or free, that is distributed through the Google Play Store.

Comment: But what if i want to distribute my free app with in-app purchases through Play Store AND through another means (say, forums or special web page)? May i have Google Checkout API for Play Store version and PayPal for another .apk of the same app to be distributed other ways?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, you cannot do that. if you want to get money for a free app, it has to be with a for-sale app of some kind, can't be done using PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation...I want to make one point clear that, kit is not the whole app which the user is to be charged for, It is only the one section of the app for which in-App purchase is to be implemented.